# Javascript Splitting Strings

Tags: javascript, string

I came across an block of Javascript code to split a paragraph with the dom structure.

The code is as follows:

```
string.split("<b" + "r>");
```

I am a little confused as to why do they have to use a PLUS SIGN and split the parameter into lookup strings?

Why not just use

```
string.split("<br>");
```

Is there a technique or browser issue involved here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is a measure against the `<br>` tag getting interpreted. In what situation this might happen, I don't know, though. Maybe some very stupid browser or parser screwed up the script and actually rendered the tag.

Comment: Yep, most likely thats the case

Comment: I remember reading about script-tags being interpreted in inline JavaScript.
The trick was to move the JavaScript to separate files.

Comment: or add comments and CDATA the javascript blocks.